# Filter content PHP

Tags: php

Trying filter content with get data:

```
<?php
    $min_quadrature = $sanitizer->text($input->get->min_quadrature);
    $max_quadrature = $sanitizer->text($input->get->max_quadrature);
    $min_price = $sanitizer->text($input->get->min_price);
    $max_price = $sanitizer->text($input->get->max_price);
?>
<div class="gallery-items four-columns grid-small-pad">
    <?php foreach($pages->find("parent=projects") as $parent): ?>
    <?php
        $show = "";
        if(!empty($min_quadrature) && !empty($max_quadrature) && !empty($min_price) && !empty($max_price) && $parent->quadrature >= $min_quadrature && $parent->quadrature <= $max_quadrature && $parent->price >= $min_price && $parent->price <= $max_price) {
            $show = "d-block";
        } else if(!empty($min_quadrature) && $parent->quadrature >= $min_quadrature) {
            $show = "d-block";
        } else if(!empty($max_quadrature) && $parent->quadrature <= $max_quadrature) {
            $show = "d-block";
        } else if(!empty($min_price) && $parent->price >= $min_price) {
            $show = "d-block";
        } else if(!empty($max_price) && $parent->price <= $max_price) {
            $show = "d-block";
        } else if(empty($max_price) && empty($min_price) && empty($min_quadrature) && empty($max_quadrature)) {
            $show = "d-block";
        } else {
            $show = "d-none";
        }
        ?>
    <div class="gallery-item projects <?= $show; ?>" data-budget="<?= $parent->price; ?>" data-quadrature="<?= $parent->quadrature; ?>">
        <div class="grid-item-holder">
            <?php 
                $image = $parent->background;
                $thumb = $image->size(300, 170); 
                ?>
            <img src="<?= $thumb->url; ?>" alt="">
            <div class="port-desc-holder">
                <div class="port-desc">
                    <div class="grid-item mt-2">
                        <h3 class="m-0"><a href="<?= $parent->url; ?>"><?= $parent->title; ?></a></h3>
                        <p class="price d-none"><?= $parent->price; ?></p>
                        <p class="quadrature p-0 m-0"><?= $parent->quadrature; ?> m2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

All my items have $min_quadrature, $max_quadrature, $min_price, $max_price

I try show blocks if input data in range, my solution working bad, some combinations with all 4 input data

Comment: Ignore images and CSS/HTML for now. Instead, dump the variables that you are testing using `var_dump` or similar in the loop, specifically the ones that aren't working as you expect. For each of the `if` blocks, dump out something extra that identifies which one is currently hitting.

Comment: Can i have example?

Comment: As the first line in your `for` loop put `var_dump($min_quadrature,$max_quadrature, $min_price, $max_price, $parent );`. Then in your `if` statements, instead of `$show = "d-block";` put something like `echo group 1`, `echo group 2`, etc. You currently have an opinion of what you want the data to look like, you now need to confirm that by manually inspecting the data.